# CakePHP set input type in view from custom array

Tags: cakephp, model, types

I would like to assign input fields in a view types from a custom array, not from a model, as Cake usually does.
So, I have in my array (passed to the view) a key which tells the field type the field in the database must have:

`[type] => 'varchar(32)'`

I would like Cake to know this field type and automagically assign it to the corresponding input field (so that, for the example above, the input will be a `text`). How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

P.S.: These are the 'transformations' I would like to achieve (from the table): [Data types correspondings in Cake](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements)

Answer (score 0):

linkyndy,

The mapping from model schema types to html form elements is done here - http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper/#l-738.  Furthermore, varchar(32) (string) will create an html input element when using the FormHelper.  Is it you want a textarea instead?

If you do not want to use the automatic field detection you can specify the element type in your call to input.  If that's not acceptable, you can change your db field types to meet what CakePHP expects... or manipulate your model's schema() results... or provide your own helper with an overridden input() method.

Specifying the type in calls to $this->Form->input() seems easy enough.

Comment: I cannot change the schema in SQL because those field types aren't 'real'. They are added as columns and represent the target table's field types. I thought it would be an easier method to do this if I have the field types stored in an array. So, the only way will be testing in the view the field type stored in the array and assigning the proper correspondence in the input()'s options array, right?